# Cannot infer type for `U`

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using Rust and Diesel:

```
fn create_asset_from_object(assets: &HashMap<String, Assets_Json>) {
    let connection: PgConnection  = establish_connection();
    println!("==========================================================");
    insert_Asset(&connection, &assets);
}

pub fn insert_Asset(conn: &PgConnection, assests: &HashMap<String, Assets_Json>){
    use self::schema::assets;

    for (currency, assetInfo) in assests {

        let new_asset = self::models::NewAssets {
            asset_name: &currency,
            aclass:  &assetInfo.aclass,
            altname: &assetInfo.altname,
            decimals:  assetInfo.decimals,
            display_decimals: assetInfo.display_decimals,
        };

       //let result = diesel::insert(&new_asset).into(assets::table).get_result(conn).expect("Error saving new post");
       println!("result, {:#?}", diesel::insert(&new_asset).into(assets::table).get_result(conn).expect("Error saving new post"));

    }
}
```

**Compiler error:**

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> src/persistence_service.rs:107:81
    |
107 |        println!("result, {:#?}", diesel::insert(&new_asset).into(assets::table).get_result(conn).expect("Error saving new post"));
    |                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `U`
```

Comment: What's your **question**? You've just pasted code and an error message.

Comment: Cannot infer question for "U".

Comment: Question is simple : How can I solve the compilation issue ?   yes robert is correct.

Comment: By providing a type for `U`.

Comment: I think the OP is right to be confused, since there is no `U` in the client code and not `U` even in the error message. So how could one start searching for what `U` needs to be specified? I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), specifically the [chapter on generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-00-generics.html).

---

[`LoadDsl::get_result`](https://docs.rs/diesel/0.16.0/diesel/prelude/trait.LoadDsl.html#method.get_result) is defined as:

```
fn get_result<U>(self, conn: &Conn) -> QueryResult<U> 
where
    Self: LoadQuery<Conn, U>,
```

In words, that means that the result of calling `get_result` will be a `QueryResult` parameterized by a type of the *callers* choice; the generic parameter `U`.

Your call of `get_result` in no way specifies the concrete type of `U`. In many cases, type inference is used to know what the type should be, but you are just printing the value. This means it could be *any* type that implements the trait and is printable, which isn't enough to conclusively decide.

You can use the *turbofish* operator:

```
foo.get_result::<SomeType>(conn)
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can save the result to a variable with a specified type:

```
let bar: QueryResult<SomeType> = foo.get_result(conn);
```

---

If you review the [Diesel tutorial](http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/), you will see a function like this (which I've edited to remove non-relevant detail):

```
pub fn create_post() -> Post {
    diesel::insert(&new_post).into(posts::table)
        .get_result(conn)
        .expect("Error saving new post")
}
```

Here, type inference kicks in because `expect` removes the `QueryResult` wrapper and the return value of the function must be a `Post`. Working backwards, the compiler knows that `U` must equal `Post`.

If you check out the [documentation for `insert`](https://docs.rs/diesel/0.16.0/diesel/fn.insert.html) you can see that you can call `execute` if you don't care to get the inserted value back:

```
diesel::insert(&new_user)
    .into(users)
    .execute(&connection)
    .unwrap();
```