# Rust Diesel raw SQL gives error "type annotations needed for `std::result::Result<Vec<T>, diesel::result::Error>`"

Tags: sql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying out simple raw SQL to MySQL using Diesel as shown in this example:

https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.sql_query.html

```rust
let users = sql_query("SELECT username FROM users").load(&connection);
```

However this gives me an error message:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `std::result::Result<Vec<T>, diesel::result::Error>`
  --> src/main.rs:53:57
   |
53 |     let users = sql_query("SELECT username FROM users").load(&connection);
   |         -----                                           ^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `U` declared on the associated function `load`
   |         |
   |         consider giving `users` the explicit type `std::result::Result<Vec<T>, diesel::result::Error>`, where the type parameter `U` is specified
```

Ps. I need to use raw sql as I need to run dynamic sql.

Comment: Do you have a struct named `User`? If yes, did you derive `#[derive(QueryableByName)]` for this struct? If yes, did you try specifying the table to which this struct relates by adding attribute `#[table_name = "users"]`? If still yes, did you know that `load(&connection)` returns a `Result<Vec<T>, Err>` which needs to be unwrapped? If still yes, then did you try  adding a type declaration on your local variable as in `let users: Vec<User> = ....`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot infer type for \`U\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255634/cannot-infer-type-for-u)

Comment: @TheCoolDrop I don’t have a User struct because I thought the raw sql would let me run dynamic sql without knowing before hand what the results would be. Is that possible? The sql I would be running will be a lot more complex and dynamic without knowing result types beforehand. How can I do so?

Comment: How can you not know the type of result? Is it so that you are executing a select ( or whatever other query ) whose structure you do not know beforehand? What is it that you will be knowing about the tables, and what pieces of information are going to be missing? Do you at least know the number of columns?

Comment: @TheCoolDrop I will have a lot of custom functions and the functions get passed various properties. Depending on the properties, the functions would return variable json with variable columns. Is there a way in rust to receive custom dynamic json without knowing what’s inside? Similar to how Swift has Any and AnyObject types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine, Diesel does not have any capability to perform queries where the 'shape' of the returned rows is not known at compile time. This is one of its strengths (at least for some use cases) because used properly, it will validate interaction with the database at compile time.

However this makes it difficult to use for dynamically generated SQL.

If your queries always generate the same number and types of columns then you can write something like this:

```
// Define a type to represent the rows returned by your query

#[derive(QueryableByName)]
struct StringColumn {
    #[sql_type = "Text"]
    username: String
}

// Then you can execute your query, telling Rust that you expect
// to get the rows back as the above type
let users:Vec<StringColumn> = diesel::sql_query("SELECT username FROM users").load(&conn)?;
```

If you are purely using dynamically generated SQL, you might be better off using the [mysql](https://docs.rs/crate/mysql/20.1.0) crate directly.

Comment: While this does work (so I accepted it) but it doesn't fit my needs. My needs are specifically that I need to run whatever SQL dynamically without having to create the struct for every query as that would require me to define every column in a struct - & thus won't be dynamic. I basically want to remove the strict type and compile time checking for SQL columns and their types. I ended up switching to Postgres Database instead of MYSQL along with `r2d2_postgres` on Rust's side. Postgres allows me to use `jsonb_agg(t)::text` to convert the results into a JSON text & I retrieve & send as `&str`