# Generic type of raw SQL query in rust

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-diesel-mysql

I have a MySQL database and I want to make the simplest possible query  in rust to verify that I'm connecting to the database and able to retrieve data.

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::mysql::MysqlConnection;
use diesel::dsl::sql_query;
use dotenvy::dotenv;
use std::env;

fn establish_connection() -> MysqlConnection {
    dotenv().ok();
    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL")
        .expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    MysqlConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
}

fn print_db_properties() {
    let connection = &mut establish_connection();
    let results = sql_query("SELECT version()")
        .load(connection)
        .expect("error");
}

fn main() {
   print_db_properties();
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed for `Vec<U>`
    --> src/main.rs:32:9
     |
32   |     let results = query
     |         ^^^^^^^
33   |         .load(connection)
     |          ---- ---------- type must be known at this point
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = note: cannot satisfy `_: FromSqlRow<Untyped, Mysql>`
     = help: the following types implement trait `FromSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
               <(T1, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, Untyped), __DB>>
             and 23 others
     = note: required for `Untyped` to implement `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<_, Mysql>`
     = note: required for `SqlQuery` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, MysqlConnection, _>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /home/bschwyn/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/diesel-2.1.4/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1543:15
     |
1541 |     fn load<'query, U>(self, conn: &mut Conn) -> QueryResult<Vec<U>>
     |        ---- required by a bound in this associated function
1542 |     where
1543 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`
help: consider giving `results` an explicit type, where the type for type parameter `U` is specified
     |
32   |     let results: Vec<U> = query
     |                ++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0283`.
```

The error is caused by a generic type not being known and could be resolved by something like:

```
let results: Vec<U> = query...
```

or

```
let results = query.load::<U>(connection).expect("error");
```

My question is how do I determine what type "U" will be?

More info:
Load is going to return a type `QueryResult<Vec<U>>` as per the [docs.](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.load) It has the definition:

```
fn load<U>(self, conn: &Conn) -> QueryResult<Vec<U>>
where
    Self: LoadQuery<Conn, U>,
```

In the [docs](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/dsl/fn.sql_query.html) there is no type referenced by "let users =..." so I'm not sure what they did differently.

Rust [does not have type introspection:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266001/how-to-introspect-all-available-methods-and-members-of-a-rust-type) , but I was able to write a print_type_of method to get the type of sql_query("...") as diesel::query_builder::sql_query::SqlQuery.

Other examples such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870030/rust-diesel-raw-sql-gives-error-type-annotations-needed-for-stdresultresul) are for queries of columns/rows and such with defined structs. Do I need something like that?

Comment: The docs fix the type of `load` by comparing it's returned value to a `Result<Vec<User>,_>` with `assert_eq!(Ok(expected_users), users)` so `users` has to be `Result<Vec<User>,_>` you'll have to tell Rust the type you want to get, too.

Comment: To be more clear that is what I'm trying to ask about. What type should it be? How would I know? It's not Users so what should I use instead? Thanks

Comment: You look at the db. i.e. do what your last sentence suggests.